# Converting string to UTF-8 using buffer

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, buffer

I need to convert a (possibly large) string to UTF-8, but I don't want to create a byte array containing the full encoding. My idea was to use a `CharsetEncoder` for this, but `CharsetEncoder` only acts on `CharBuffer`, which means that supplemental characters (outside the Unicode range `0x0000` to `0xFFFF`) should be considered.

Now the method I *was* using was `CharBuffer.wrap(String.substring(start, start + BLOCK_SIZE))`, and my `ByteBuffer` is created using `ByteBuffer.allocate((int) Math.ceil(encoder.maxBytesPerChar() * BLOCK_SIZE))`. However, `CharBuffer` will now contain `BLOCK_SIZE` code points, not code units (characters); I think the actual amount of characters will be two times `BLOCK_SIZE` as maximum. This means that my `ByteBuffer` is two times too small as well.

How can I calculate the correct amount of bytes for my `ByteBuffer`? I could simply double it in case each and every character is a supplemental character, but that seems a bit much. But the only other reasonable option seems to iterate over all code units (characters) or code points, which at least *looks* suboptimal.

Any hints on what's the most efficient approach to encode Strings piecemeal? Should I use the buffer, the iteration with `String.codePointAt(location)`, or is there an encoding routine that directly handles code points?

---

Additional requirement: invalid character encodings should result in an exception, default substitution or skipping of invalid characters cannot be allowed.

Comment: What do you want to do with the utf-8 bytes? Is there a reason to not just use a BufferedWriter wrapping a FileWriter or OutputStreamWriter; both of which can have the character encoding to use (utf-8) defined at construction.

Comment: `FileWriter` is not possible because of default char encoding, `OutputStreamWriter` uses character substitution which I don't want either. Anyway, I think I may be able to answer myself - you can simply wrap the entire `String` instance.

Comment: @BrettOkken Main thing is to feed it into a `MessageDigest`.

Comment: If you are going to utf-8, there should not be any character substitution.

Comment: @BrettOkken There seem to be character codes that are not accepted, even for Unicode characters (that surprised me as well). I'll test if they generate an exception or a substitution, but they are certainly there (I decided to test with a randomly generated string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is easier to simply wrap the whole string, and then blindly read characters until none are remaining. No need to cut the string in parts, the encoder will just read bytes until the output buffer is filled up:

```
final CharsetEncoder encoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder();
final CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap(input);
final ByteBuffer encodedBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
CoderResult coderResult;

while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
    coderResult = encoder.encode(buffer, encodedBuffer, false);
    if (coderResult.isError()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid code point in input string");
    }
    encodedBuffer.flip();
    // do stuff with encodedBuffer
    encodedBuffer.clear();
}

// required by encoder: call encode with true to indicate end
coderResult = encoder.encode(buffer, encodedBuffer, true);
if (coderResult.isError()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Invalid code point in input string");
}
encodedBuffer.flip();
// do stuff with encodedBuffer
encodedBuffer.clear(); // if still required
```